# The complex function $f(z)=\sin (\frac{1}{z})$ is not bounded near $ z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that the function $f(z)=\sin (\frac{1}{z})$ is not bounded near $ z=0$. Can anyone know an example of a sequence $(z_n)$ that converges to $0$ but $f(z_n)$ converges at $\infty$? I try to find some but nothing is correct. Also, I tried to apply Liouville's theorem but $f$ must be holomorphic all over the Complex plane. Any Ideas? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you approach along the imaginary axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure imaginary numbers $iy$ with $y \in \mathbb R$, you have

$$\sin(iy) = i \sinh(y)$$

Hence $$f\left(\frac{1}{in}\right)= \sin(in) = i \sinh(n).$$

As $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sinh n = \infty$, one desired sequence is $\{\frac{1}{in}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ is bounded near zero. Then $\lim_{z\to 0} (z-a) f(z)=0$, which means that $\sin(\frac{1}{z})$ has a holomorphic continuation $g:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ which is continuous at $z=0$: $$\lim_{\substack{z\to 0\\ z\neq 0}} g(z)=g(0)\in \mathbb{C}$$This isn't possible since $\lim_{\substack{z\to 0\\ z\neq 0}} g(z)=\lim_{\substack{z\to 0\\ z\neq 0}} f(z)$ doesn't exist (Consider the sequences $z_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and $w_n=\frac{1}{2\pi n +\pi/2}$).